# Skewed population example

Tags: skewness, population

> "Consider a strongly skewed population (e.g., waiting times at airport security screening)."

My book always uses that example when referring to skewed populations. I don't understand why would that specific situation have a skewed graph.

Comment: Waiting times vary from small positive to arbitrarily large. Usually small positive, at least compared with the arbitrarily large. Now imagine sketching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airlines wait times, in the US, are about 30 - 45 minutes in major hubs. However, time to time major delays or increased travelers can create extremely large outliers, skewing the average wait time up.

If you're interested to know more, day-to-day average wait time and tallies on wait time brackets in the US can be downloaded [here](http://awt.cbp.gov/). Nothing beats checking the facts ourselves. It does not include, as far as I know, the security check time, but I believe they are likely quite correlated.

Comment: Security screening has an additional component that your correct answer misses.  Airline wait times are all roughly equal on any give day, people queue up in one line and wait their turn to be in the front.  The security line behaves slightly differently.  _Most_ passengers have roughly equal weight time (e.g. ~10 minutes on a light travel day) but some get pulled aside for additional screen that can take hours.  This is the skew I assumed the book was talking about.